# SSRS - Multiple Value Parameter - Expression regarded 'All' option

Tags: arrays, reporting-services, parameter-passing

I have a SSRS report and one of the parameters allows multiple selections and I have also added an 'All' option which will pass a '' to the database and select all departments for example.

So in the drop down we have something like:

(Select All)

All (Code '')

HR (Code 1)

IT (Code 2)

Management (Code 3)

So the (Select All) is the standard option with multi select and the (All) is a custom one to pass a null/''.  We have the additional (All) to allow all departments (some not in the list ) to be returned.  What I want to do is understand what is passed to the DB if I select (All) along side other options - so if I select (All) and HR?  At the moment if I select this - just the results for HR will show.

I want to be able to write a condition that says if they have selected (All) do this,  but I am not sure how the array is passed?  I want to imitate what is being passed by the report when (All) is selected?

Comment: You should be creating a deliminated list from a multipick parameter. If you are using commas it should look like "Null,HR". Add some logic to your parameter proc logic to remove the All option and just keep the default Select All from the multi pick. In your report split the string into a table and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the built-in Select All option is chosen, SSRS sets the parameter to be all of the possible values as a comma separated list, which is passed to your dataset.  Your custom All has its own value, that is sent as a single value that you would handle differently then the rest.

Assuming that your All parameter is valued as 'All', in your dataset query, the where clause would need to be

```
WWHERE dept IN (@dept) OR 'All' IN (@dept)
```

If your All & HR are selected, the query would be the functional equivalent of

```
WHERE dept IN ('HR','All') OR 'All' IN ('HR','All')
```

There are some performance implications so make sure you test with multiple options.

Comment: Many thanks - This solution pointing me in the right direction and I've been able to resolve